# Arcmap layout view zoom data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, layouts

I have a map in ArcMap that I would like to export as an image, adding also a legend and so on. My issue is that when I go to the Layout View, my data occupy only a small part of the layout view. I would like to zoom in the data, but if I try I do not zoom the data, but the whole layout view.

How can I zoom in in layout view to enlarge the view of my data without zooming the layout view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the highlighted tool for zooming your data inside your Layout.
[image: zoom]

Comment: Ok, it was easier than expected. Thank you I did not know it

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to set your map extent :
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/customizing-your-map-extent.htm